# how to get the http headers of Server software and set the timeout

Tags: php, http-headers

I'm trying to get the HTTP headers but just the server software example: Apache, Microsoft-iis,Nginx,etc

The function

```
get_headers($url,1);
```

it is too slow i want to set time out if it is possible or an other way ??

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "want to set time out"?

Comment: @MattS i have a list of hosts and i want to retreive their server software if the host is offline it take long time to pass to an other host

Comment: Ooh... see my answer update below...

Answer (score 1):

For the local server, the [$_SERVER](http://docforge.com/wiki/PHP/Superglobals/%24_SERVER) variable will give you everything exposed by the web server in SERVER_* keys.

For remote servers you can use libcurl and request just the headers.  Then parse the response.  It can still be long delay depending on network connectivity and the speed of the other server.  To avoid a long delay, e.g. for an offline server, set the curl option for a short timeout (e.g. 5 seconds) using `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5)`.

Comment: i want to get the server software of a list of server not local server thanks

Comment: but i want just to get the server software from the output like Server:Apache i want just to get this line can u help ?? thanks

Comment: See williamvicary's answer, then use a regex on the return string, e.g. preg_match('/Server:(.*)$/i', $header, $matches);

Answer (score 1):

This would set the code to timeout after 2 seconds, you can use CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS if you want milliseconds.

```
$timeoutSecs = 2;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // Return the header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); // Don't return the body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Return to a variable instead of echoing
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeoutSecs);

$header = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Edit: Note you won't just be able to get a single header from this, it will return the whole header (which won't be any slower than getting just one segment to be honest) so you will need to create a pattern to pull the "Server:" header.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with cURL, which will allow you to get the response from remote servers. You can set a timeout with cURL as well.

Comment: You mean just get the name? cURL for the headers, then parse it out. It's in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Get the headers by curl or fsockopen, parse it that you want .

the function of fsockopen is last argument for a timeout.

the function of curl calls "curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5) " that for a timeout.

For example:

```
function getHttpHead($url) {
$url = parse_url($url);
if($fp = @fsockopen($url['host'],empty($url['port']) ? 80 : $url['port'],$error,
    $errstr,2)) {
    fputs($fp,"GET " . (empty($url['path']) ? '/' : $url['path']) . " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fputs($fp,"Host:$url[host]\r\n\r\n");
    $ret = '';
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $tmp = fgets($fp);
        if(trim($tmp) == '') {
            break;
        }
        $ret .= $tmp;
    }
    preg_match('/[\r\n]Server\:\s([a-zA-Z]*)/is',$ret,$match);
    return $match[1];
    //return $ret;
} else {
    return null;
}
}
$servername= getHttpHead('http://google.com');

echo $servername;
```

Comment: HAHA, i think i have not any better way . get_headers，fsockopen,curl.... any others? waiting...